# Align a tikzpicture inside or outside a tabular?

Tags: tables, graphics

Sorry for the title, I'm just looking for a solution to a problem I have.

I would like to generate a report that's based on several events, with, in one column, an icon that shows what event occured, and in the other, the details.

Visually, it currently looks like this:

[image: current result]

As you can see, it seems that the icon is aligned with the other column's second row, while I wish it could take the whole height, I'm even ok if it stretches it. Another solution would be to place the icon outside the table, and to repeat the process but I haven't found a solution for that yet.

Here is my current code:

```latex
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=\dimexpr15mm+1.5\baselineskip,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\icon}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle (1cm);
            \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.5cm]{#1}};
        \end{scope}
        \draw[black] (0,0) circle (.5cm); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\icon{example-image-a}} & 01/01/2023 à 00:00 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & Début d'intervention sur le site "Eglise St Martin" \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\icon{example-image-b}} & 01/01/2023 à 00:00 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & L'utilisateur pre sdis a rejoint le site. \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\icon{example-image-c}} & 01/01/2023 à 00:05 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & "Statue Marie" a reçu le statut "En cours de protection" \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the baseline of the tikzpicture with the `baseline=...` option:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=\dimexpr15mm+1.5\baselineskip,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\icon}[1]{{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=1mm]
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle (0.35cm);
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{#1}};
        \end{scope}
        \node[circle,draw,minimum width=0.7cm] (icon) at (0,0) {}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow[t]{2}{*}{\icon{example-image-a}} & 01/01/2023 à 00:00 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & Début d'intervention sur le site "Eglise St Martin" \\ \hline
    \multirow[t]{2}{*}{\icon{example-image-b}} & 01/01/2023 à 00:00 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & L'utilisateur pre sdis a rejoint le site. \\ \hline
    \multirow[t]{2}{*}{\icon{example-image-c}} & 01/01/2023 à 00:05 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & "Statue Marie" a reçu le statut "En cours de protection" \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use the `tabularray` package and get a nice alignment out of the box:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=\dimexpr15mm+1.5\baselineskip,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcommand{\icon}[1]{{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle (0.35cm);
            \node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{#1}};
        \end{scope}
        \node[circle,draw,minimum width=0.7cm] (icon) at (0,0) {}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tblr}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \SetCell[r=2]{} \icon{example-image-a} & 01/01/2023 à 00:00 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & Début d'intervention sur le site "Eglise St Martin" \\ \hline
    \SetCell[r=2]{} \icon{example-image-b} & 01/01/2023 à 00:00 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & L'utilisateur pre sdis a rejoint le site. \\ \hline
     \SetCell[r=2]{} \icon{example-image-c} & 01/01/2023 à 00:05 \\ \cline{2-2} 
     & "Statue Marie" a reçu le statut "En cours de protection" \\ \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the result is exactly what I tried to get!

Comment: @Jaeger You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

I added `baseline` to move baseline of the tikz image to its middle point. With `clip`, doesn't seem to be changing a minimum size. For that reason, I added an extra invisible rectangle to simulate padding around the images.

As to the table itself, I would definitely suggest `tabularray` for this example, which distributes its content evenly.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=\dimexpr15mm+1.5\baselineskip,bottom=2cm]{geometry}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\padding}{0.25cm,0.25cm}

\newcommand{\icon}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,0) circle (0.5cm);
      \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{#1}};
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) circle (.5cm);
    \draw [draw=none]
    ($(current bounding box.south west) - (\padding)$)
    rectangle
    ($(current bounding box.north east) + (\padding)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={Q[c] Q[l]},
      column{1} = {colsep=0pt},
      vlines, hlines,
      vspan=even,
    }
    \SetCell[r=2]{} \icon{example-image-a}
    & 01/01/2023 à 00:00 \\
    & Début d'intervention sur le site "Eglise St Martin" \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} \icon{example-image-b}
    & 01/01/2023 à 00:00 \\
    & L'utilisateur pre sdis a rejoint le site. \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{} \icon{example-image-c}
    & 01/01/2023 à 00:05 \\
    & "Statue Marie" a reçu le statut "En cours de protection" \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]